# Leaflet map contextmenu showing at the left top corner in the first time

Tags: javascript, leaflet, contextmenu

I added a context menu to map in the leaflet. Before the first `contextmenu` event, the `contextMenu` displays in the left-top corner on the map.

```
let options = { 
    maxZoom: 20 ,
    contextmenu: true,
    contextmenuItems: this.mapContextMenuItems
}

this.map = L.map("map", options).setView([0, 0], 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the position of this menu by adding 'position' in your options like that :

```
let options = { 
    maxZoom: 20 ,
    contextmenu: true,
    contextmenuItems: this.mapContextMenuItems,
    // Here :
    position: 'topleft', // or 'topright' or 'bottomleft' or 'bottomright'
 }
this.map = L.map("map", options).setView([0, 0], 1);
```

Comment: So remove it from your options: let options = { 
    maxZoom: 20 ,
    contextmenu: false
 }

Comment: Or directly : this.map = L.map("map", {maxZoom: 20 , contextmenu: false }).setView([0, 0], 1);

Comment: I want to display the contextmenu, but just after contextmenu event

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `map.contextmenu.hide()` after initializing

https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.contextmenu#methods
https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.contextmenu/blob/69478afd4af9adf19ed743847cc9294e396a4d13/src/Map.ContextMenu.js#L78

Comment: have you a online demo?

Answer (score 0):

add:
    .leaflet-contextmenu{
    display:none}
In the style sheet.
The contextmenu hides at first, and only appears in 'contextmenu' event.
In 'contextmenu' event, leaflet add 'display:block' to the leaflet-contextmenu element, inline. this definition overrides the style-sheet definition.

Can anyone explain why in the beginning the leaflet contextmenu display is not set to none?